# How to solve the problem in function without any use of libraries

Tags: python, file-handling

Read the file 'test.csv' and change the Grade of Rohit's grade to A and save the file to 'test.csv'

Example -

```
Read -  Name,Class,Subject,Grade
        Ajay,   10, English,A
        Rohit,  9,  English,B
        Chaman, 10, English,A
        Rudra,  9,  English,C
        Rajesh, 10, English,B

Write - Name,Class,Subject,Grade
        Ajay,   10, English,A
        Rohit,  9,  English,A
        Chaman, 10, English,A
        Rudra,  9,  English,C
        Rajesh, 10, English,B
```

Explanation read the csv file and then store the data into local variable and again write that data using writerow function of csv module (Note: Don't forget to use 
newline='' when opening the csv file in write mode)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please show us what you did and where you encountered a specific problem in achieving this homework.

Comment: I think you came here to get your homework solved.Show some hardwork before.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by using the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module's [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [`writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) objects:

```
import csv

# Variable initialization.
name = 'Rohit'
gradeToChange = 'A'
data = []

# Opening and reading csv file to get its rows and perform the change in Rohit's grade.
with open('data.csv', 'r') as inFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')
    data = [row for row in csvReader]
    for i in range(1,len(data)):
        if data[i][0] == name:
            data[i][3] = gradeToChange
            break

# Writing the modified data back to the file.
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline="") as outFile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for elem in data:
        csvWriter.writerow(elem)
```